# Some Game Dev questions?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

It is a noob question, but Im starting dealing with programming, c# to be clear. So our teacher gave us this code:

```
var asteroid = collision.GetComponent\<AsteroidController\>();

if (asteroid != null)
{
    Destroy(asteroid.gameObject);
}
```

We are developing a game, so I have 4 scripts, Asteroid Controller, PlayerController and Bullet Controller

In Bullet Controller I have the code for player destroy the gameobject that has the script Asteroid Controller.

My question is, in wich script do I need to put thiis line of code.

I put the code in asteroidcontroller but is doing some errors
[image]

Comment: I'd recommend asking your teacher for guidance on the assignment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Collision detection not working unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43939179/collision-detection-not-working-unity)

Comment: @Ruzihm I don't think so .. OP has the code not even in the correct method which should probably be `OnCollisionEnter` ;)

Answer (score 1):

So you are using the Unity Engine, the code will be different in different game engines.

In Unity's `MonoBehaviour` class there are a few functions that get called when special conditions are met. You can read more about what functions are called and when [HERE](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html).

Currently your code is under one of these functions Called `Update` which gets called every frame. For collisions you want to use a different function called `OnCollisionEnter`, you can read up on it [HERE](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter.html).

If we look at the function is looks something like this:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
   ...
}
```

And as we can see it has a `Collision` parameter by default. Meaning your code will resolve and work:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    var player = collision.gameobject.GetComponent<PlayerController>();
    if (player != null)
    {
        Destroy(player.gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: There's also [some setup](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html) for colliders on your objects. `Notes: Collision events are only sent if one of the colliders also has a non-kinematic rigidbody attached`. Unity doesn't check every object for collisions, only the things you tell it to check. That saves cpu overhead.